# Clear Way To Update Widget TextView

Tags: android, android-widget, textview, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

The amount of time ive spent trying to get methods like `Timer`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `AlarmManager` etc. to work. All i need is a **clear** way to update the widget or textview every second.

```
java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

String time = "kk:mm";
String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));
views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
```

I basically need this to set the text either when the time changes or update every second. Every method ive tried has failed. Can someone please give me the best way to do this and how?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Handler and a Thread:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // update your textview here.
    }
};

class TickThread extends Thread {
    private boolean mRun; 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRun = true;

        while(mRun) {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i call the RemoteViews from OnUpdate to update the TextView's?

Comment: No idea, if this is an additional question - you'd best start another. And if my answer answered your original question then please mark it as accepted.